# Bluetooth read incoming character one at a time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have a small question about Bluetooth communication, I've been going through a tutorial on YouTube on how to create an app that communicates with my arduino. Everything is going fine; however my only problem is that when I test for incoming data from arduino in the phone the string data seems to be tested randomly using Stringbuilder thus the test sometimes may or may not work. The data received is as follows "B1234." Lettet B indicates which data is received, the following numbers are the data itself and the dot indicates the end of stream. I'm New to android so I'm sorry if my question is not as clear as it should be 
Here's the onReceive java code for BluetoothConnectionService:

```
byte [] buffer = new byte [1024];
int bytes;
//Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
while(true) {
    try { 
        bytes mainstream.read(buffer);
        String incomingMessage = new String (buffer, 0, bytes);
        Intent incomingMessageIntent = new Intent ("incomingMessage");
        incomingMessageIntent.putExtra ("theMessage", incomingMessage);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance (mContext).sendBroadcast(incomingMessageIntent);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        break;
    }
}
```

And here's the received java code in MainActivity:

```
publix final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver5 = new BroadcastReceiver () {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String text = intent.getStringExtra ("theMessage");
        messages.append(text); //Append StringBuilder
        FragmentData.RXData.setText (messages);
        messages.setLength(0); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sending the data in a loop?  or just once?

Comment: I suspect you BroadcastReceiver is not in sync with UI thread. So most of the time it misses the append(). The solution is to use a handler perhaps.

Comment: The data is sent continuously from arduino to the phone. I will try and use the handler as you mentioned and see if that works